# Group Position returns always 0

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have been tinkering with this problem for atleast 5 hours and I can't wrap my head around it. I have expandable listview and groupposition is always returned as 0. Because of that. HashMap from which I take data out is always starting with one value. I loged out childposition and groupposition in "getChildView" but it always starts with 0

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){

            CategoryItem x = (CategoryItem)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            Log.d("EGILS",Integer.toString(groupPosition)+" "+Integer.toString(childPosition));
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

            TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_Virsraksts);
            TextView price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_Cena);
            name.setText(x.getItem_name());
            price.setText("€"+Double.toString(GV.round(x.getPrice_notax(),2)));

        }
        //return secondlvl;
       return convertView;

    }
```

This is the function that im getting my childView out, after that getChild

```
@Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    Log.d("GINTS2", Integer.toString(childPosition) + " " + this.categoryItems.get(this.subcategories.get(groupPosition).getId()).get(childPosition).getItem_name());

        return (Object)this.categoryItems.get(this.subcategories.get(groupPosition).getId()).get(childPosition);
    }
```

The funny thing is that when i log out groupposition in get childview i allways get 0

```
//1st GROUP PRESSED
11-06 02:50:41.551  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 0

 11-06 02:50:41.561  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 1

11-06 02:50:41.566  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 2

 11-06 02:50:41.571  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 3
//2nd GROUP PRESSED
11-06 02:50:47.052  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 0
//3rd GROUP PRESSED
 11-06 02:50:50.533  19665-19665/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/EGILS﹕ 0 0
```

Logged out GetGroupView (group position)

```
11-06 12:07:17.609  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 0 -
11-06 12:07:17.624  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 1 -
11-06 12:07:17.624  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 2 -
11-06 12:07:17.676  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 0 -
11-06 12:07:17.676  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 1 -
11-06 12:07:17.676  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 2 -
11-06 12:07:17.677  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 0 -
11-06 12:07:17.677  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 1 -
11-06 12:07:17.683  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 2 -
11-06 12:07:17.689  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 0 -
11-06 12:07:17.691  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 1 -
11-06 12:07:17.691  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 2 -
11-06 12:07:17.725  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 0 -
11-06 12:07:17.726  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 1 -
11-06 12:07:17.726  30767-30767/com.martinssinka.projektaizmaksas D/GROUPPo﹕ 2 -
```

Comment: what value does your `getGroupCount` returns?

Comment: you are not consider the case where convertView is not null

Comment: @njzk2    
It returns 3. `return this.subcategories.size();` And if convertView were problem it wouldnt even show me the logs.

Comment: Could you log out the `groupPosition` in `getGroupView`?

Comment: suit yourself. but I am telling you the problem *is* that you are not handling the case where convertView is not null. And it is not showing you the log for those views, because you are logging inside you if block.

Comment: @njzk2 I logged out groupposition in getgroupview. And its wierd that it gives me a lot of these views. If your suggested thing about convertView is correct, what would be the best possible solution to fix this problem?

Comment: at its simplest, the `if (convertView == null)` block should only contain `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ...; convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);`. Every thing else goes after that block. (Then you can consider using the view holder pattern, but that is optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what i did was created new project and copied all the classes and layouts into new project. And worked like a charm.

Don't know what happened, i assumed it was probably a glitch .